# Converting a physical Windows partition into a VM for use with KVM, and then configuring the Windows VM as a router for my Linux host?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, router

So bassically, I'm in year 11 and go to highschool. I have got a Linux laptop and asked them to connect Linux to their network (which they do for Windows/Mac computers). They didn't want to (it's not just an open network I can connect to, I think the network requires certain certificates that has to be generated by one of the schools servers or something). I dualboot Windows and Linux so they were willing to connect my Windows partition to their network though.

And now you can start to see where my question is coming from. What I want to do is convert my Windows partition into a virtual machine (with my wifi and ethernet passed through), then I want to make Windows act as a router for my host. So I can use my Windows VM to indirectly connect my Linux host to the network.

Does this seem possible?
I know this isn't really about servers, but it deals with a lot of stuff servers have to deal with, so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: Sorry, but this site isn't "about servers", it's about business environments, so your question is off topic here and I'm voting to close it.
A hint you can follow: If you have a valid certificate for 802.1x authentication in your windows you can export it there and configure the same certificate in your linux installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use V2V converter to achieve this goal.
Here is a good article about these tools:
http://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/